# How to sort all lists in a deeply nested dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I want to sort all lists within a deeply nested dictionary. It is basically a JSON object which deep nesting of dictionaries within lists and then lists within dictionaries. All I want to do is, parse through all dictionary keys to all leaf nodes and sort all the lists that i encounter on the way. Basically, any list directly available or deep down within that given dictionary object should get sorted and the same dictionary with all sorted lists should be returned.

I tried doing recursion on the dict object to pass any dict object encountered to the recursion method and sorting the lists when encountered. But they fail to produce results when there is a dict inside a list and then another list inside that dict object.

Sample JSON below:

```
my_json = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: [
        {
          d: [
            { f: 'some_string' }
          ]
        },
        {
          e: {
            g: [
              h: 'another string'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  z: [
    b: {
      c: [
        {
          d: [
            { f: 'some_string1' }
          ]
        },
        {
          e: {
            g: [
              h: 'another string1'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    x: {
      c: [
        {
          d: [
            { f: 'some_string2' }
          ]
        },
        {
          e: {
            g: [
              h: 'another string2'
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
def gen_dict_extract(input_dict):
  result_obj = input_dict;
  if hasattr(var, 'iteritems'):
    for k, v in var.iteritems():
      if isinstance(v, dict):
        for result in gen_dict_extract(v):
          yield result
      elif isinstance(v, list):
        v.sort();
        for d in v:
          for result in gen_dict_extract(d):
            yield result
```

The output expectation is just to have all lists sorted irrespective of where they lie. I am even okay with sorting every item in the dictionary but list sorting is what I require.

Taking a smaller example here to explain the output:

```
old_json = {
    'x': [
        {
            'z': {
                'y': ['agsd', 'xef', 'sdsd', 'erer']
            }
        },
        {
            's': {
                'f': 'ererer',
                'd': [5, 6, 2, 3, 1]
            }
        }
    ]
}

new_json = {
    'x': [
        {
            's': {
                'f': 'ererer',
                'd': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
            }
        },
        {
            'z': {
                'y': ['agsd', 'erer', 'sdsd','xef']
            }
        }
    ]
}

Something like above.
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] to illustrate what you've tried and the specific problem with it.

Comment: I know you've tried really hard to explain the output you're looking for but I still don't get it. Can you update your post include what the sample JSON would get converted to explicitly? In the question please!

Comment: Please add your expected output in question. That will help us to solve your issue easily.

Comment: Done.. Please take a look. Please ignore my code as it might not serve the exact purpose i am looking for.

Comment: Please revisit your input data. Looks like there are some syntax errors

Comment: I had just put a sample json to show how it can look like, did not check for its validation. Have validated it now. Please check.

Comment: Note that sorting a dictionary's keys doesn't make much sense. Technically you could do it since Python 3.7, but it's a bit tricky.

Comment: I am not concerned about the dictionary keys, my concern is to reorder list elements in sorted form.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output to be a different dictionary (i.e. not sorting the original), the function should be written like this:

```
def sortedDeep(d):
    if isinstance(d,list):
        return sorted( sortedDeep(v) for v in d )
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        return { k: sortedDeep(d[k]) for k in sorted(d)}
    return d
```

This way you can use sortedDeep() the same way you would use the buil-in sorted() function:

```
new_json = sortedDeep(old_json)
```

[EDIT] Improved version that will also sort lists of dictionaries (or list of lists) based on the smallest key/value of the embedded object:

```
def sortedDeep(d):
    def makeTuple(v): return (*v,) if isinstance(v,(list,dict)) else (v,)
    if isinstance(d,list):
        return sorted( map(sortedDeep,d) ,key=makeTuple )
    if isinstance(d,dict):
        return { k: sortedDeep(d[k]) for k in sorted(d)}
    return d
```

Comment: This will work for a dict without duplicate keys. How about when we have to sort a dict with duplicate keys?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a dictionary with duplicate keys.  By definition the keys in a dictionary are unique.

Comment: Sorry, I meant JSON. How to deep sort when JSON has duplicate keys? And it can be a list of json of list and so on.

Comment: I don't think JSON supports duplicate keys in a dictionary either. But, if your question pertains to a 'list of dictionaries' (or list of objects in JSON vernacular), then it won't work as is. I added an improved version that will do it based on the smallest key of each dictionary in the list.

Comment: I have a payload something like this: `ls = {'payload': [{'a': {'aa': [{'aa12': {'aaa23': 230, 'aaa21': 210}}, {'aa11': {'aaa12': 120, 'aaa11': 110}}, {'aa13': {'aaa35': 350, 'aaa32': 320}}], 'ac': ['ac3', 'ac1', 'ac2'], 'aa': [{'aa12': {'aaa22': 22, 'aaa21': 21}}, {'aa01': {'aaa03': 03, 'aaa01': 01}}, {'aa13': {'aaa33': 33, 'aaa32': 32}}, {'aa1': 'aab'}], 'ac': ['ac3', 'ac1', 'ac2']}}, {'b': {'bb': ['bb4', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb1']}}]}`. How do I sort this? With the above code, it is still removing duplicate keys.

Comment: And also `(*v,)` seems to be throwing an error. It's not unpacking as expected.

Comment: Works fine when I try you structure, except that `{'aaa03': 03, 'aaa01': 01}` is invalid because of the leading zeroes in 03 and 01.  Fixing that, `sortedDeep(ls)` gives the right answer (Python 3.7).

Comment: Oh. I was using Python 2.7. I get response as `{'payload': [{'a': {'aa': [{'aa01': {'aaa03': 3, 'aaa01': 1}}, {'aa1': 'aab'}, {'aa12': {'aaa21': 21, 'aaa22': 22}}, {'aa13': {'aaa33': 33, 'aaa32': 32}}], 'ac': ['ac1', 'ac2', 'ac3']}}, {'b': {'bb': ['bb1', 'bb2', 'bb3', 'bb4']}}]}`. Where in `{"aa12": {"aaa23": 230, "aaa21": 210}}, {"aa11": {"aaa12": 120, "aaa11": 110}}, {"aa13": {"aaa35": 350, "aaa32": 320}}` has been removed from the response.

Comment: We can assume the leading zeros can be removed from the above payload. Can you please suggest a possible solution in v2.7?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the constraints of Python 2.7. I learned Python at version 3.6. Perhaps someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code snippet here will do the job for sorting nested dictionaries.

```
def nested_sort(d:dict):
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            nested_sort(v)
        elif isinstance(v,list):
            v.sort()
```

However, I cannot test the code because the example you gave is not in legal JSON format or a legal python dictionary.